# Azure Data Factory - Calling Logic App Synchronously

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

As part of our flow we are calling an logic app from our ADF. Logic app calls other  website with REST calls and some other task related to containers.

However, the problem is,  Call from ADF to Logic App is Asynchronous, So even if Logic App fails ADF pipeline is success.

Is there any way to either make it synchronous, such that ADF pipeline wait until Logic App is finishes, and it fails or pass based on the status of logic App.

or, is there any way I can poll the status Logic App from within ADF?

Comment: Do you use If Conditions in your pipeline? You can do your App to output an result and send it as parameter to the next If condition evaluate it for success or fail.

Comment: @Praetorian1995 I could do that, however would be able to show how to pass parameter from logic app to ADF pipeline?

Comment: you can see how to do it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom Web API request that receives an success or fail state and you then you can send that parameter to your pipeline.

For example you create a custom task for the API request.
[image]

Then you build the pipeline with an Lookup to the received state and does an action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a dev in ADF.

You can use Webhook activity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-webhook-activity to call your logic app passing the callback url as a parameter. At the end of your logic app, you can add an action to call this callback url and pass the status that you need for your ADF to mark it as succeeded/failed